# How can I match the two dataframe and get the following result?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:
payment is the line of payment name with value

```
payment = pd.DataFrame({'Payment':["payment1","payment2","payment3"],'Value':[100,200,300]})

Payment     Value
payment1    100
payment2    200
payment3    300
```

and project_cost is the line of project name with their cost

```
project_cost = pd.DataFrame({'Project':["Project1","Project2","Project3"],'Cost':[200,300,400]})

Project        Cost
Project1       200
Project2       300
Project3       400
```

I basically want to match the payment with the project.

How can I get the following dataframe?

```
Project     Cost      Payment 
Project1     100      payment1
Project1     100      payment2
Project2     100      payment2
Project2     200      payment3
Project3     100      payment3
Project3     300
```

The last row of payment left empty because there is a deficit of payment to pay the project.

Is there anything I can do in the pandas to get this result?
Thanks a lot

The following is the logic of my dataframe:
[image: I have added this image to help you understand my logic]

The payment is broken down to match with the project.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I understand the question properly, but if you want to merge both the data frames then you would need to have atleast one column to match i.e., "Value" or "Cost". So if you have the below input

```
payment = pd.DataFrame({'Payment':["payment1","payment2","payment3"],'Cost':[100,200,300]})
project_cost = pd.DataFrame({'Project':["Project1","Project2","Project3"],'Cost':[200,300,400]})
```

Then you can merge the two data frames by using merge in pandas

```
result = pd.merge(payment, project_cost, on= 'Cost')
```

Let me know if I understood the problem correctly.

Edit:

```
    Payment Cost    Project
0   payment1    200 Project1
1   payment2    200 Project1
2   payment3    200 Project1
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: it is kind of merging the dataframe but there are some additional logic inside.
I want to merge the project and payment dataframe but the payment shall match with the project first.

Comment: I have added a image to help you to understand my logic behind.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work for the sample data. You should check it a little more. The idea is that you compute the accumulation (`cumsum`) of the costs and the payments. Then you can sort them increasingly and try to propagate the `Payment` and `Project` accordingly.

```
project_cost['accum'] = project_cost['Cost'].cumsum()
payment['accum'] = payment['Value'].cumsum()

(payment.merge(project_cost, on='accum', how='outer')
    .sort_values('accum')
    .bfill()
)
```

Output:

```
    Payment  Value  accum   Project   Cost
0  payment1  100.0    100  Project1  200.0
3  payment2  200.0    200  Project1  200.0
1  payment2  200.0    300  Project2  300.0
4  payment3  300.0    500  Project2  300.0
2  payment3  300.0    600  Project3  400.0
5       NaN    NaN    900  Project3  400.0
```