# How can I match the two data frame and get the following result?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have the following df_project:

```
df_project = pd.DataFrame({'Project':['A','B','C'],'Day':[1,5,10],'Cost':[100,200,300]})

Project Day Cost
A       1   100
B       5   200
C       10  300
```

I also have the following df_payment:

```
df_payment = pd.DataFrame({'Payment':['P1','P2','P3','P4','P5','P6'],'Day':[2,3,5,6,7,11],'Amount':[50,40,100,50,70,280]})

Payment Day Amount
P1      2   50
P2      3   40
P3      5   100
P4      6   50
P5      7   70
P6      11  280
```

I want to get the following result:

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame({'Project':['A','A','A','B','B','B','np.Nan','C','C'],'Payment':['P1','P2',np.nan,'P3','P4','P5','P5','P6',np.nan],'Amount':[50,40,10,100,50,50,20,280,20]})

Project Payment Amount
A       P1      50.0
A       P2      40.0
A       NaN     10.0
B       P3      100.0
B       P4      50.0
B       P5      50.0
NaN     P5      20.0
C       P6      280.0
C       NaN     20.0
```

The logic is that:
1. The payment must match with the project with day is greater or equal to

so we can see P1 and P2 match to A, P3,P4,P5 match to B and P6 match to C

2. After matching the payment with project 
   we basically have the following dataframe:

```
Project Payment 
A       P1      
A       P2      
B       P3      
B       P4      
B       P5      
C       P6
```

then we also match the df_payment['Amount'] with df_project['Cost']

So (P1,50) and (P2,40) are matched to A, but A have a cost of 100, there is a deficit of 10 so the payment is set to NaN

Then for Project B, (P3,100),(P4,50),(P5,70) have a surplus of 20 so the project is set to NaN for the extra 20 surplus

Similarily, for projectC (P6,280) have a 20 deficit so the result will be like this:

```
Project Payment Amount
A       P1      50.0
A       P2      40.0
A       NaN     10.0
B       P3      100.0
B       P4      50.0
B       P5      50.0
NaN     P5      20.0
C       P6      280.0
C       NaN     20.0
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: why isnt P3 and P4 matched with A, since the days are greater than 1? could you explain ur logic a bit better

Comment: @sammywemmy Since they are greater than 5 so they will match with B first. maybe we can perform matching in descending order?

Comment: Is it a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60312492/how-can-i-match-the-two-dataframe-and-get-the-following-result/60313254#60313254) of yours?

Comment: This one is different to the previous one. This one involved the day comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) to merge on the closest days

```
M = pd.merge_asof(df_payment,df_project,on='Day').drop('Day',axis=1)
```

function helps attach difference between Cost and Amount back to the dataframe

```
def attach_difference(df):
    A = df.Amount.sum()
    B = df.Cost.max()
    C = df.shape[0]
    D = df.Payment.iloc[-1]
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
    if A-B < 0:
        df.loc[C]=  {'Payment':np.nan,
                     'Amount':abs(A-B), 
                     'Project':df.Project.unique()[0],
                     'Cost':np.nan}

    elif A - B > 0 : 
        df.loc[C-1,'Amount'] = df.loc[C-1,'Amount'] - (A-B)
        df.loc[C]=  {'Payment':D,
                     'Amount':A-B, 
                     'Project':np.nan,
                     'Cost':np.nan}


    return df
```

run a list comprehension and pipe the function to each group

```
outcome = [group.pipe(attach_difference)
           .drop('Cost',axis=1)
           for name, group in M.groupby('Project')]

(pd.concat(outcome,ignore_index=True)
 .reindex(['Project','Payment','Amount'],
          axis=1)
 )



   Project  Payment Amount
0     A       P1    50
1     A       P2    40
2     A       NaN   10
3     B       P3    100
4     B       P4    50
5     B       P5    50
6     NaN     P5    20
7     C       P6    280
8     C       NaN   20
```

Comment: wow the merge_asof function is so powerful! Thank you so much!

Comment: hi sammywemmy, I tried to use the above code and it run well. However, when I try to have extra column on  df_project / df_payment, Error occur: ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: extra columns means you have to make changes to the function; have a look at the function and adapt it to your new logic. especially the A - B part and the appending back to the dataframe.